# Bootstrap 3 Accordion - target first div with class name within nested divs

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

This question pertains to Bootstrap 3 accordion. I'm trying to remove to top border of only the first panel-heading.
Obviously :first-child, nth-child(1), :first-of type is not working as the panel-heading is situated inside a panel div.

```
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
         <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#0" aria-expanded="false">Headline-1</a>
         </h4>
     </div>
     <div id="0" class="panel-collapse collapse" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 0px;">
       <div class="panel-body">
         <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</div>
       </div>
     </div>
    </div>

    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title"><a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#1" aria-expanded="false">Headline-2</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="0" class="panel-collapse collapse" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 0px;">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title"><a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#2" aria-expanded="false">Headline-3</a></h4>
      </div>
      <div id="0" class="panel-collapse collapse" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 0px;">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
    .panel-heading{
      border-top: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
      border-bottom: none;
      border-radius: 0;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, blank moment

just had to target the `.panel:first-child .panel-heading`